# Big-O Nested While Loop

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

```
i <-- 1
while(i < n)
   j <--1
   while(j < i)
      j <-- j * 2
   i <-- i + 1
done
```

My shot at this would be `O(log n)` for the inner loop. And I'm guessing the outer loop is `O(n)`, for an overall complexity of `O(n log n)`. Confirm?

Comment: looks right to me overall, though the inner loop I believe is actually log n / 2 due to it being based on i.  The divide by 2 is not usually shown in big O though so I believe you are correct.

Comment: BTW, if you were to change the psuedo code to 'C' code and mark it as such, you would get a lot more views.

Comment: No. Since you're not doing anything inside the loop, the compiler will optimize it away :-)

Answer (score 8):

You may proceed formally, step by step, using Sigma notation to obtain the exact number of iterations - Look at [Discrete Loops and Worst Case Performance](http://www.auto.tuwien.ac.at/~blieb/papers/discloop.pdf) paper (page 10).

[image]

The result has been empirically verified.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, but it is not that simple to figure it out correctly :).

Inner loop is trivial `log n`, there is no need for further explanation.

However the outer loop is not that simple, because in each cycle it changes how long the inner cycle is executed.

If you think about it, the inner cycle will be run for (as `i` increases) :

```
log 1 + log 2 + log 3 + log 4 + log 5 .... + log n
```

Due to the some laws of logharitms, it is same as `log (1*2*3*4*....*n)` which is same as

`log (n!)`

There is a law that `n!` has same complexity (beware, it is complexity, it is not same in algebra) as `n^n`

Therefore `log (n!) = O(log (n^n))`

Now we can just switch back to algebra, because `log (n^k) = k*log (n)` we get the result

`log (n^n)` = `n log n`

**Result :**

Time complexity is `O(n log n)`

Comment: The law is called Stirling's approximation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation